# Very strange behavior of bs4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse my html-doc with audio metadata, and I've wrote the function:

```
from bs4 import *
import warnings
import re
import sys

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def pairing(soup,
            author_class: tuple,
            track_class: tuple,
            subclass: tuple) -> dict:
    
    use_dict = {}

    for pair in zip(
            soup.find_all(author_class[0], {"class": author_class[1]}),
            soup.find_all(track_class[0], {"class": track_class[1]}),
            soup.find_all(subclass[0], {"class": subclass[1]})
    ):
        """
        pair[0] - musician(-s), 
        pair[1] - track_name, 
        pair[2] - subtitle for track(if any)
        """
        print(pair[0],"\n", pair[1], '\n', pair[2])

        track_author = pair[0].find('a').text
        # Clear row
        track_author = re.sub('[!@#$_]', '', track_author)

        try:
            add_meta = pair[2].find('span').text
        except AttributeError:
            print(sys.exc_info())
            add_meta = ""

        track_name = pair[1].text + add_meta
        # Clear
        track_name = re.sub('[!@#$_]', '', track_name)

        use_dict.update({track_author: track_name})
    return use_dict
```

And the problem is nearby try-except contrustion: when I ask for track_author - no problem, everything OK. Note that not all tracks have subtitle, so sometimes this tag (span) is empty(None). But my code thinks that it is empty in any iteration. It's quite strange and confusing, because code with track_author above looks the same and works. I need to return text inside subclass(if any), otherwise return empty row.
Output from terminal:

```
<div class="audio_row__performers"><a>John Paesano</a></div> 
 <span class="audio_row__title_inner _audio_row__title_inner">The Final Lesson</span> 
 <span class="audio_row__title_inner_subtitle _audio_row__title_inner_subtitle"></span>
(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"), <traceback object at 0x7fb32d283f80>)

<div class="audio_row__performers"><a>The Blue Notes</a></div> 
 <span class="audio_row__title_inner _audio_row__title_inner">Halo Theme</span> 
 <span class="audio_row__title_inner_subtitle _audio_row__title_inner_subtitle">Piano Rendition</span>
(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"), <traceback object at 0x7fb32d267ec0>)
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to go in another way - regex.

```
def pairing(soup,
            author_class: tuple,
            track_class: tuple,
            subclass: tuple) -> dict:

    use_dict = {}

    for pair in zip(
            soup.find_all(author_class[0], {"class": author_class[1]}),
            soup.find_all(track_class[0], {"class": track_class[1]}),
            soup.find_all(subclass[0], {"class": subclass[1]})
    ):
        """
        pair[0] - musician(-s), 
        pair[1] - track_name, 
        pair[2] - subtitle for track(if any)
        """

        track_author = pair[0].find('a').text
        # Clear row
        track_author = sub('[!@#$_]', '', track_author)

        pair_2_str = str(pair[2])

        regex = "(?<=>).*?(?=<)"
        add_meta = findall(regex, pair_2_str)[0]

        track_name = pair[1].text + f" {add_meta}"
        # Clear
        track_name = sub('[!@#$_]', '', track_name)

        use_dict.update({track_author: track_name})
    return use_dict
```